# How to use data_utils.WeightedRandomSampler and still be able shuffle training data in Pytorch?

Tags: classification, sampling, weights, multilabel

I am working on the multi-label classification task in Pytorch  and I have imbalanced data in my model, therefore I use `data_utils.WeightedRandomSampler` method which helps me to balance my weights during the training part. However, it has its disadvantage , according to the pytorch if sampler is chosen, then Dataloader cannot shuffle data, i.e. it should be set to false as follows:

```
trainloader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size = batch_size, sampler = sampler, shuffle=False, num_workers = 0)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to avoid it, since I really prefer to shuffle my data during training since as I noticed, the accuracy is increased in that case.

Answer (score 3):

`WeightedRandomSampler` samples randomly from a given dataset. It effectively does the shuffling for you.

On the flip side, you actually can't turn *off* shuffling when you use this sampler.